# Vlan Routing with ESXI and L3 Cisco Switch

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, vmware

Please, i need your help. I have read all the posts from the internet, but i don't know what is wrong.
i want to ping from PC10 (portgroup in Vlan 10 with ip 1.1.10.200, GW 1.1.10.2) to the int vlan 10 from the switch (ip 1.1.10.2) but it says Destination host unreacheable.
I want to configure a topology with a Cisco L3 Switch with vlan routing between 2 VM's created inside an ESXi host.

TOPOLOGY WITH ESXI AND GNS3
[image]

So i have the following:
- on my laptop i have installed VMWare Workstation
- inside the workstation i created 2 VM's:  one ESXI host and one GNS3 VM Server
- on ESXI host i have created two VM's:
                -----PC10 on portgroup V10 allocated to Vlan 10 with ip 1.1.10.200/24 GW 1.1.10.2
                -----PC20 on portgroup V20 allocated to Vlan 20 with ip 1.1.20.200/24 GW 1.1.20.2
                -----the management interface has the ip: 10.10.10.10

ESXI CONFIGURATION
[image]

- the switch is configured as a L3 SW:
              ----- the switch runs inside the GNS3 VM and it is a QEMU VIRL image
              ----- i have created vlan 10 and vlan 20
              ----- int vlan 10 with ip 1.1.10.2
              ----- int vlan 20 with ip 1.1.20.2
              ----- int g0/0 (connected to ESXI host) is configured as a trunk

SWITCH CONFIGURATION

### [image]

I want to mention that i have tested the connectivity between the switch and a PC inside the ESXI and it worked as follows:
- Switch: int g0/0 (connects to ESXi host) --- no switchport
                                           --- ip addr 10.10.10.2/24
- ESXI host: mangement int - 10.10.10.10 GW 10.10.10.2
- PC inside ESXI: ip add 10.10.10.200 GW 10.10.10.2 (connected to VM Network)
- no vlan configuration was done, neither inside the switch, nor inside ESXI.

I have just wanted to test connectivity between switch and PC inside ESXi, and after that to configure vlan. But it didn;t work.

Comment: Please post text configurations as text (using the { } function) and NOT AS SCREENSHOT!

Comment: You can't trunk VLANs outside of GNS3. you'll need to run your ESXI inside it.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? How should i do?

Comment: You can't trunk vlans to VMWare workstation

Comment: K. Thank you! So how should i do this lab to make vlan routing work between an ESXi with VM's and a cisco router/switch?